# Как получить значения объектов коллекции IEnumerable класса и вывести их на экран

Tags: linq

Пожалуйста помогите. Как получить значения объектов класса Class1, используя IEnumerable и linq и вывести их на экран?

```
введите код здесь

namespace ConsoleIEnumerable
  {
  public static class Program
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
       Console.WriteLine(Class5.ToString());
       Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Class1> Class5
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
 }
}

public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            FIO = "Петров";
            Age = 30;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Идентификатор
        /// </summary>
        public virtual long Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Число
        /// </summary>
        public virtual int Number { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// ФИО
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string FIO { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Возраст
        /// </summary>
        public virtual int Age { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", FIO, Age);
        }
    }
```

Данный код приводит к ошибке ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Comment: так может вам стоит  инициализировать Class5, которое вы почему-то инициализировать не пожелали?

Comment: как его инициализировать?

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class5 = new List<Class1>();

            Console.WriteLine(Class5.Select(x => x.FIO.ToString()));
           Console.ReadLine();
        }

Если сделать вот так то я получаю не значение поле FIO класса, а имя класса, как получить тогда значение?

Comment: про статические конструкторы и инициализацию статических полей что-нибудь слышали?